# Show full posts in archive

Tags: php, themes, archives

I have an issue where I need to display the full posts in my archive page.

E.G. I have >two posts and I would like to have EACH of them displayed in full in the archive page. Thanks!

How would I do this with the hueman theme?

Here is the contents of the archive.php theme:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="content">

    <?php get_template_part('inc/page-title'); ?>
    <?php if(function_exists('pf_show_link')){echo pf_show_link();} ?>
    <div class="pad group">     

        <?php if ((category_description() != '') && !is_paged()) : ?>
            <div class="notebox">
                <?php echo category_description(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="post-list group">
                <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
                <?php if($i % 2 == 0) { echo '</div><div class="post-row">'; } $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
            </div><!--/.post-list-->

            <?php get_template_part('inc/pagination'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!--/.pad-->

</section><!--/.content-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the content.php file:

" >

```
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-medium'); ?>
            <?php elseif ( ot_get_option('placeholder') != 'off' ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/thumb-medium.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_format('video') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>'; ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_format('audio') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span>'; ?>
            <?php if ( is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>'; ?>
        </a>
        <?php if ( comments_open() && ( ot_get_option( 'comment-count' ) != 'off' ) ): ?>
            <a class="post-comments" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--/.post-thumbnail-->

    <div class="post-meta group">
        <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(' / '); ?></p>
        <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('j M, Y'); ?></p>
    </div><!--/.post-meta-->

    <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2><!--/.post-title-->

    <?php if (ot_get_option('excerpt-length') != '0'): ?>
    <div class="entry excerpt">             
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!--/.entry-->
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!--/.post-inner-->
```

Thanks for your interest!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What relevant template files does your Theme include?

Comment: I have tried using the `<?php the_content(); ?>` php code snip bit but that only shows the full most recent post.

Comment: `the_content()` is the correct function, so you must not have it in the right place. Not familiar with the theme to correct you, but agree with Pieter's suggestion of a child theme.

Comment: I will post the content of the archive.php file in the question

Comment: The `archive.php` code you posted doesn't call either `the_content()` or `the_excerpt()`. You probably need to look in `content.php`, which is included in `archive.php` via `get_template_part( 'content' )`.

Comment: K I will put that into the question also!

Comment: I don't know php and I know a little HTML so I am mostly guessing on where to put the code snip bit... lol

Comment: In `content.php`, do you see `the_excerpt()` being called?

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes...

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `the_content()`? If so: what happened? Did it work?

Comment: @ChipBennett
It works for the top posts but it is still cutting off the bottom posts. It is a good start! :)

Comment: Here is the address of the site: augustagemandmineralsociety.org

Comment: @ChipBennett I have added `<?php the_content(); ?>` to the code and it now shows as much as possible but it cuts the bottom of the bottom posts off and adds an ellipsis `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following in a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), do not make changes to the theme itself.

**EDIT**

I had a good look at the 'Heuman' theme. I think to solve your problem here is to copy the following files to your child theme, `content.php` and `archive.php`

Rename your `content.php` to something like `content-archive.php`. Open it up and delete the following lines

```
<?php if (ot_get_option('excerpt-length') != '0'): ?>
 <div class="entry excerpt">                
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div><!--/.entry-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

and replace it with

```
<div class="entry content">             
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!--/.entry-->
```

Next, open up your `archive.php` and replace he following line

```
<?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
```

with

```
<?php get_template_part('content', 'archive'); ?>
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: I tried this and it gives me this error. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/content/09/3046609/html/wp-content/themes/hueman/content.php on line 32`

Comment: Sorry about that, forget one `)` in elseif function. Updated my answer

Comment: I will try this setup in just a bit! Thanks for the update!

Comment: Semi: it shows the full posts until it gets to the bottom of the page, where it cuts them off... Thanks for you help so far!